# how to get last approved version of (currently rejected) share point list item using jsom

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have a SharePoint custom list in Office 365

**I need to get the last approved version of the list items including the currently rejected item (which might have a previous approved version)**

When I checked using the CAML builder I was able to see 
(0)- approved (1)- rejected (2) -pending  in the status column.

The Image I have attached will show the Approved and Rejected Version of Item 1,however I'm only able to see the rejected status in the CAML builder.

**Is it possible to get the last approved version of list item using jsom (in my case the version 2.0 of list item 1)**

Note : There is no minor versions used , only major version.
       This is attempted using the Napa in Office 365.

[image: The First Image is the list view , the second is the version view of first list item entry]